# Assign a variable variable in Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop with the jquery .each function that is filtering through IDs with the suffix _prop_val I then get the prefix and use it for other operations as you can see in the code below. At the moment I am having to use an if statement to set the rlPrice. Is there a way to get it in the loop i.e. prefixPrice and then have it set as rlPrice afterwards

```
$('[id$="_prop_val"]').each(function(){
    var prefix = this.id.slice(0,2);
    if( $('#'+prefix+'_prop_val').val() != ""){
        $('#'+prefix+'_prop_val').prop('disabled', false).trigger('chosen:updated');
        $('#'+prefix+'_ct_row').show();
        $('#'+prefix+'_deactivate_btn').show();
        if(prefix == "rl"){
            rlPrice = $('#rl option:selected').data("unit-price");
        }
        checkExtra(prefix);
    }else{
        $('#'+prefix+'_container').addClass('inactive');
        $('#'+prefix+'_activate_btn').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the use of `rlPrice`?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Are you saying that you want to use a local variable named `prefixPrice` while in the loop, but after the loop completes, you'd like to assign the value of `prefixPrice` to `rlPrice`?

Comment: Prefix is going to be rl, rs, cl or bm. Loop goes through and creates a variable called rlPrice. I want to create it using the prefix. So first time round rlPrice is created the next time rsPrice is created. Trying to not use if statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find an object more useful here. Define it before the loop:

```
var price = {};
```

Then in your loop just assign the price to a property with the prefix as a key - no need to check for a condition:

```
price[prefix] = $('#rl option:selected').data("unit-price");
```

Then you can just access the price using the prefix:

```
var rlPrice = price['rl'];
```

Comment: Sorry its not the value I looking to get but the actual prefix text. rl in rl_prop_val or rs in rs_prop_val and as the loop works set a variable called rlPrice and rsPrice using [prefixtext]Price, is that possible? Or maybe im doing it wrong altogether

Comment: With this method you don't need to create dynamically named variables (which is horrible btw).

Comment: Ah yes so I just assign them at the end thens o rlPrice = price['rl']; rsPrice = price['rs']; clPrice = price['cl']; bmPrice = price['bm'];

Comment: @PierceMcGeough, you don't even need to define `rlPrice`. Anytime you need a particular price just call the `price` object with the prefix. (I only added `rlPrice` as a demonstration.)

Comment: Ah yes i see that now. Thanks :)