# Use javascript to assign a dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which works on changing different dropdowns with same ending ID. I have variables assigned elsewhere rl and rl_extra rs and rs_extra.

The var prefix will come back with on of those two rl or rs. I then want to check if the rl is equal to the value but I need the rl variable to be called through the prefix.

So if the prefix == "rl" then the rl and rl_extra variables are rl throught the prefix. Likewise if the prefix == "rs" then the rl variable shown is actuall rs and rs_extra.

Is there a way to asign a variable variable maybe?

```
$('[id$="_prop_val"], [id$="_extra_val"]').change(function(){
    var prefix = this.id.slice(0,2);
    if(  rl == $('#'+prefix+'_prop_val').val() 
         && rl_extra == $('#'+prefix+'_extra_val').val()){
        $('#'+prefix+'_nt_row').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('#'+prefix+'_nt_row').show();
    }
    getPrices();
    displayNMP();
});
```

Comment: [Isn't this the same question you asked yesterday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141700/assign-a-variable-variable-in-javascript-loop/21141877#21141877)

Comment: Unfortunately not, because this time the code is isolated. Yesterdays I could call what I wanted anywhere but this all happens inside that function and have no idea what the var and var_extra will actually be (unless i do an if statement to check first of all)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you mean, you could do something like this: instead of rl, rl_extra, rs, rs_extra, and so on, use an object with properties:

```
var props = {
    "rl": rl, // Or you could use the selector directly here and skip the rl declaration entirely
    "rl_extra": ...,
    "rs": ...,
    "rs_extra": ...,
    "xy": ...,
    "xy_extra": ...,
    ...
};
```

And then:

```
$('[id$="_prop_val"], [id$="_extra_val"]').change(function() {
    var prefix = this.id.slice(0,2);
    if (props[prefix] == $('#'+prefix+'_prop_val').val() && props[prefix + "_extra"] == $('#'+prefix+'_extra_val').val()) {
        $('#'+prefix+'_nt_row').hide();
    } else {
        $('#'+prefix+'_nt_row').show();
    }
    getPrices();
    displayNMP();
});
```

Comment: Sorry I have other vars too that are assigned like this rl = $('#rl_prop_val').val(); rl_extra = $('#rl_extra_val').val(); rs = $('#rs_prop_val').val(); rs_extra = $('#rs_extra_val').val(); cl = $('#cl_prop_val').val(); cl_extra = $('#cl_extra_val').val(); bm = $('#bm_prop_val').val(); bm_extra = $('#bm_extra_val').val();

Comment: @PierceMcGeough: Too easily, wouldn't it? Just extend the object(s) with further properties.

Comment: If they work in the same way, yes, you can extend the object or use other similar objects (basically, a two-property object for each alternative couple of variables). Do cl and bm work like rl and rs?

Comment: Yes and there will end up being more - pp, ss and another. Heres a js of what im trying to do jsbin.com/afuWebIh/1 If the selects are the same as when the page loads then hide the new total row. The code at the very bottom is what I am looking at. I use the if(prefix == "rl"){ to check which is being changed but I want to do it without using the multiple ifs

Comment: Ok, so you can just use a single big object with a property for each of these variables you were using. I edited the answer for clarity, see if it makes sense to you.

Comment: Yes that makes sence but which way do I assign my rl and rl_extra values now. Will it still be rl = $('#rl_prop_val').val(); rl_extra = $('#rl_extra_val').val(); or now props['rl'] = $('#rl_prop_val').val(); and props['rl_extra'] = $('#rl_extra_val').val();

Comment: Well, you can choose either. You can do `rl = $(...).val()` with `props["rl"] = rl` afterward, or you can just go with `props["rl"] = $(...).val()` without even defining the `rl` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `data-*` HTML element attributes.

**jQuery .data() function:** http://api.jquery.com/data/
**Further reading:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

So your JS code would look something like this:

```
$(".dropdown").change(function(){

  var associated_element = $('#'+this.data("associated-id"));
  var associated_value_to_match = this.data("associated-value");

  if (associated_element.val() == associated_value_to_match)
    associated_element.hide();
  else
    associated_element.show();

  getPrices();
  displayNMP();

}
```

And your HTML code would look something like this:

```
<select class="dropdown" id="first" data-associated-id="second" data-associated-value="2">
</select>
<select class="dropdown" id="second" data-associated-id="third" data-associated-value="3">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

I'm a bit hazy on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but the above should give you the gist of how to associate metadata with your HTML elements, and moreover, use it in your JS logic.

Comment: Here is a jsbin http://jsbin.com/afuWebIh/1/
The code at the very bottom is what I am looking at. I use the if(prefix == "rl"){ to check which is being changed but I want to do it without using the multiple ifs